# How can i complete the lines of a grid with cv2.HoughLinesP?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, sudoku, hough-transform

I'm trying to extract a grid from a sudoku puzzle, using cv2.HoughLinesP(). After processing the image (converting to a binary image), i appplied the function cv2.HoughLinesP() above:

```
def houghtransf(warp):
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(binary_image, 2, np.pi/2, 500, minLineLength=200, maxLineGap=10)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(binary_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
for l in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = l[0]
    cv2.line(frame,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2, cv2.LINE_AA)
return frame

lines = houghtransf(binary_image)
cv2.imshow('grid', lines)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

After that, i get the following image:[Grid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmn6F.jpg)

I need to extract the intersections of the lines, but in the top right corner, the lines don't intersect.
Is there any way to complete those lines and make them intersect?

Comment: Draw all lines until end of the square. Why you need to draw not completed lines, make them longer ıuntil end

Comment: But how can i do that? Because with the code above, some of the lines stopped before the end. I don't know how i can stretch the lines